# How to extend Bootstrap-wysihtml5 editor with image upload from URL?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, upload, image-uploading, wysihtml5

I'm currently using Bootstrap-wysihtml5 text editor on my editable areas. Now I want to add image upload feature to my editor. But image's source should be URL only.

When I insert new image link to editor's image insert area;

1. It should download image to my server
2. It should check downloaded image for size, mime type etc
3. If everything ok, then I will upload it to my S3 bucket

I already coded number 2 and 3 but I can't handle number 1. How to trigger wysihtml5 editor for URL image upload when I click to insert?

Someone here did it: https://github.com/bassjobsen/wysihtml5-image-upload **but** it use traditional upload. Not from any url.

See demo: http://www.w3masters.nl/bootstrap-wysihtml5/

---

I want to implement upload feature but from URL only. What should I do before start scripting? Does it take days, weeks for beginner javascript coder?

For example stackoverflow's Image feature support Link from the web. Do you have any idea or source about it?

[image]

On above image you can insert new image but you can't store that image on your server. Image source should be my own domain after I insert image from URL

Here you can see insert image from URL feature without upload capability: http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available already here: http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/ (use the rightmost button in the toolbar).

Comment: It gets link from it's source. I want to get that image and then store that image on my Amazon S3 Bucket

Comment: This requires server-side code, so my suggestion would be to use AJAX. When inserting an image, the javascript code should send an AJAX request with the original URL to your server. The server will download the image from the URL, upload it to your storage provider, and return a new URL on your server as a response. Bootstrap-wysihtml5 should then use the URL in the response instead to insert the image into the field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$($('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents().find('body')).on("drop", function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();  
              event.stopPropagation();
               var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
                        var files = dt.files;

              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = function (e) {
                    debugger;
                  var data = this.result;
                  vm.composer.commands.exec('insertImage',e.target.result);
              }
              reader.readAsDataURL( files[0] );
          });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/surajmahajan007/2yu456nw/